# Bootstrap 3: Create an overlay on panel-body

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display some information on the panel for which I need a overlay which should be displayed on user raised event.

I've created a demo on [BootPly](http://www.bootply.com/116313):

**HTML of a single panel:**(Rest is written in the link.. NOt relavent to my question)

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888;">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">
                                    Vehicle Status Comparison <span class="pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Show Full Screen"></i>&nbsp;
                                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
                                            title="Show options"></i>&nbsp; <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-container="body"
                                                data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" title="Information" data-content="This is a very useful information. But I do not know what to write here.">
                                            </i>&nbsp; <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-retweet" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"
                                                title="Toggle Chart"></i>&nbsp; </span>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="c_VehicleStatusFull">
                                </div>
                                <div class="overlay" style="display: none">
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay
 {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
     z-index: 9999;
     color: white;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

JS:

The use of JS is to show and hide the ".overlay" div

```
$('.glyphicon-pushpin').click(function () {
     $('.overlay').toggle();
});
```

**Note:**

Please note that in the link I've given, I've hardcoded the `.panel-body` height to 100px but in actual it is adjusted at runtime.

Problem:

On cliking the "Show options" icon.. The overlay is spread all over the div but I want it to stay within 'div .panel-body'

[image: Improper Overlay]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this css

```
.panel-body { height:100px; position:relative; }
```